# Lost 109 Reputation Points

Tags: support

Today I posted a question (which has not appeared) and subsequently lost 109 reputation points! 
Surely it wasn't *that* bad?

Comment: Usually such things happen when post is classified as spam. Hope, moderators will clarify soon.

Comment: It was a simple question about exponentiation.

Comment: You have 8 badges (http://math.stackexchange.com/users/1770/thudanblunder); is that the wrong count?

Comment: @Thudan Note, that meta and main site has the same rep but different badges.

Comment: @Thudan Now you can edit the question to make _mathematical_ question more clear — then it (hopefully) will be reopened...

Comment: @Grigory: Thanks for that info. I have duly amended my original whinge.

Answer (score 10):

The spam flag was my fault; sorry. I was trying to test whether I could dismiss a spam flag as invalid, but apparently if a moderator flags a question as spam the question is automatically locked and deleted, and the flag also doesn't show up in the queue. Whoops!

In my defense, I made sure to test on a closed question with a lot of downvotes. In the future, if you want to ask a mathematical question, stick to the mathematical question.

Comment: If you undelete and clear the flags, he should be restored.

Comment: Done. So I can dismiss spam flags on _questions_ as invalid, but not (as far as I can tell) spam flags on _comments._ Hmm.

Comment: Your conduct has always been inspiring, to put your hand up like this makes one wonder how did so many good attributes have accumulated in person.

Answer (score 4):

This was the question in question I believe:

> Based on certain observations, I used
>   to jokingly claim that IQ + EQ =
>   constant, where both IQ and EQ are
>   reals.   I later mischeivously refined
>   this to $IQ^E$$^Q = $ constant.
>   However, if outliers are considered it
>   might be more accurate to exponentiate
>   EQ times. :-)
>
> Can we derive meaningful properties of
>   such exponetiation?

This is the link: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/47560/a-function-of-iq-and-eq (need 10k+ to see).

This has a score of -7 (-8 + 1) and was deleted by the Community user (mostly likely because it got enough spam votes).

This would give you a net reputation of -100 (spam) - 16 (downvotes) + 5 (upvote) = -109.

Personally, I would not have flagged as spam, but would have voted to close as not a real question: which in fact did occur, so the spam flags (if indeed they occurred) surprise me.

Comment: I thought that it was meaningful to ask wether we can exponentiate other than an integer number of times.

Comment: Yes, this is really not what spam flags are intended to be used for. The question is not spam ("*This question is effectively an advertisement with no disclosure. It is not useful or relevant, but promotional.*") nor is it offensive ("*This question contains content that a reasonable person would consider offensive, abusive, or hate speech.*"). It may not be a good question, but there are other tools to deal with that.

Comment: Huh, that was strange. I only see 1 spam flag on that question. I am not sure that was supposed to happen. (Of course, I may also just be reading some of the tabulated information wrong.) I hope someone from the SE team can clarify.

Comment: @ThudanBlunder: that is not how I read your question. The bulk of it was a silly joke and I could not get a mathematical question out of it, only some kind of request to help you extend the joke further, which is not an appropriate question.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan: OK, sorry in future I will remember not to mix business with pleasure. :-)

Comment: To put this to bed - yes, I should have been more formal but "This question contains content that a reasonable person would consider offensive, abusive, or hate speech." is way over the top. If a book about failure doesn't sell is it a success? :-P

Comment: Thanks for returning my points. :-)